# Entity Framework - Bad performance when querying remote databases

Tags: database, performance, entity-framework

I evaluated several .NET database access technologies for our new project and recognized a bad performance behavior when querying remote databases with the Entity Framework. Entity Framework was 10 times slower than LinqToSql or the SqlClient. Maybe you can help me to explain or fix that?

Test parameters:

Database:

- SQL Server 2008 Enterprise
- one table with 1000 records
- table structure:

  ```
  [dbo].[Master](
         [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
         [Value_Bit] [bit] NOT NULL,
         [Value_Float] [float] NOT NULL,
         [Value_DateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
         [Value_Uniqueidentifier] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
         [Value_NVarchar100] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
         [Value_NVarchar1000] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL,
         [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
         [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
         [Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL)
  ```

Benchmark application:

- .NET Framework 4 and 4.5
- hosted as a WinForms-Application

Database access technologies:

- Entity Framework 5.0 (RC) and 4.3.1
- LinqToSQL
- SqlClient

Computers (client/servers):

- three different computers with similar hardware
- A and B are in the same subnet (e.g. 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2)
- C is in a different subnet than A and B (e.g. 192.168.2.1)

I executed the sql query `select * from Master` directly with each database access technology on different computers as client or server. The average time is the result of 1000 iterations.

Test scenario 1:

- client: A
- server: A
- Entity Framework: average time: 17 ms
- LinqToSQL: average time: 20 ms
- SqlClient: average time: 15 ms

Test scenario 2:

- client: A
- server: B
- Entity Framework: average time: 144 ms
- LinqToSQL: average time: 141 ms
- SqlClient: average time: 140 ms

Test scenario 3:

- client: A
- server: C
- Entity Framework: average time: 2145 ms
- LinqToSQL: average time: 151 ms
- SqlClient: average time: 156 ms

Test scenario 4:

- client: B
- server: C
- Entity Framework: average time: 2060 ms
- LinqToSQL: average time: 141 ms
- SqlClient: average time: 178 ms

Why is the Entity Framework in test scenario 3 and 4 10 times slower than LinqToSQL or the SqlClient?

I tested it with Entity Framework 4.3.1, 5 (RC) and under the .NET Framework 4 and 4.5, each time the same result. I disabled lazy loading and tracking, used compiled queries and pre-generation of view, but no difference.

I used the SQL Profiler to investigate the executed SQL query and found out, that the query of the Entity Framework already took two seconds in the SQL Server (test scenario 3). If I execute the query from the Management Studio on computer A it took only 100 ms.

I profiled my benchmark application with dotTrace (http://www.jetbrains.com) and found out, that the most of the execution time is consumed by the method `ToList`. If I go deeper in the call stack I see the method `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32)` and at the end `SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SafeHandle, IntPtr&, Int32)` that consumes all the time. LinqToSql uses the SqlClient too and has almost the same call stack, but the execution time is 10 times faster.

I don't know what is going on under the hood. Maybe it has something to do with the computer name resolution, but I can ping computer C over IP address and its computer name. Is there anyone who can explain that or have an advice how to make the execution faster?

Thanks in advance

Mathias

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing you code it is hard to give any informed guess, but there are a few typical things with the EF that you could have a look at in general.

- Often you can speed up things dramatically by using [Compiled Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx).
- The deferred execution of EF queries can be a non-obvious trap when looking at the code.

An often seen mistake is doing a query that returns an IEnumerable or IQueryable collection and then using this in a loop:

```
// Execution will be deferred:
IEnumerable<person> peopleList = objectContext.People.Where(item => item.ID > 100);
foreach (person somePerson in peopleList)
{
  // do something here
}
```

This code will do many, many round-trips to the databse which can cause heavy performance issues. Du to the deferred execution an d lazy loading this would cause the code **for each item** in the peoples list to query the database again. Depending on the volume of data this is transferred over your network this alone can do severe damage to the performance.

You could reduce this overhead by simply calling ToList() method on the collection. This fetches all resulting objects in just one round-trip:

```
// Execution will be deferred:
List<person> peopleList = objectContext.People.Where(item => item.ID > 100)
                                              .ToList(); // Fetch objects NOW!
```

MSDN provides an article with some suggestions, [Performance Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx):

> **Strategies for Improving Performance**
>   You can improve the overall
>   performance of queries in the Entity Framework by using the following
>   strategies.
>
> **Pre-generate views**
>
> Generating views based on an entity
>   model is a significant cost the first time that an application
>   executes a query. Use the EdmGen.exe utility to pre-generate views as
>   a Visual Basic or C# code file that can be added to the project during
>   design. You could also use the Text Template Transformation Toolkit to
>   generate pre-compiled views. Pre-generated views are validated at
>   runtime to ensure that they are consistent with the current version of
>   the specified entity model. For more information, see How to:
>   Pre-Generate Views to Improve Query Performance (Entity Framework) and
>   Isolating Performance with Precompiled/Pre-generated Views in the
>   Entity Framework 4. When working with very large models, the following
>   consideration applies: The .NET metadata format limits the number of
>   user string characters in a given binary to 16,777,215 (0xFFFFFF). If
>   you are generating views for a very large model and the view file
>   reaches this size limit, you will get the "No logical space left to
>   create more user strings." compile error. This size limitation applies
>   to all managed binaries. For more information see the blog that
>   demonstrates how to avoid the error when working with large and
>   complex models.
>
> **Consider using the NoTracking merge option for queries**
>
> There is a cost required to track returned objects in the object
>   context. Detecting changes to objects and ensuring that multiple
>   requests for the same logical entity return the same object instance
>   requires that objects be attached to an ObjectContext instance. If you
>   do not plan to make updates or deletes to objects and do not require
>   identity management , consider using the NoTracking merge options when
>   you execute queries.
>
> **Return the correct amount of data**
>
> In some
>   scenarios, specifying a query path using the Include method is much
>   faster because it requires fewer round trips to the database. However,
>   in other scenarios, additional round trips to the database to load
>   related objects may be faster because the simpler queries with fewer
>   joins result in less redundancy of data. Because of this, we recommend
>   that you test the performance of various ways to retrieve related
>   objects. For more information, see Shaping Query Results (Entity
>   Framework). To avoid returning too much data in a single query,
>   consider paging the results of the query into more manageable groups.
>   For more information, see How to: Page Through Query Results (Entity
>   Framework).
>
> **Limit the scope of the ObjectContext**
>
> In most cases, you
>   should create an ObjectContext instance within a using statement
>   (Using…End Using in Visual Basic). This can increase performance by
>   ensuring that the resources associated with the object context are
>   disposed automatically when the code exits the statement block.
>   However, when controls are bound to objects managed by the object
>   context, the ObjectContext instance should be maintained as long as
>   the binding is needed and disposed of manually. For more information,
>   see Managing Resources in Object Services (Entity Framework).
>
> **Consider opening the database connection manually**
>
> When your application
>   executes a series of object queries or frequently calls SaveChanges to
>   persist create, update, and delete operations to the data source, the
>   Entity Framework must continuously open and close the connection to
>   the data source. In these situations, consider manually opening the
>   connection at the start of these operations and either closing or
>   disposing of the connection when the operations are complete. For more
>   information, see Managing Connections and Transactions in the Entity
>   Framework.

Comment: Oops, it seems like you already posted your own answer while I was writing mine. Nevermind... I still hope this can be at least a little bit be helpful for general cases....

Answer (score 2):

the problem respectively the huge time gap disappeared suddenly. I was told that the administrators changed something on the network, therefore I deduce that it has something to do with that, because I have not changed anything at the test parameters.

Unfortunately, I have no idea what they have changed and guess that I will never be able to find out. Pretty dissapointing, because I know that I don't know what the reason is.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to corporate america.